# Tkinter: Why the perimeter of a rectangle grid is not showing?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to use Tkinter to draw a grid into a rectangle with several rows and columns. I almost have it but, I don't know why, two lines of the perimeter are not showing in the canvas.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class GridWindow:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent

        self.myContainer1 = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.myContainer1.pack()

        self.cellwidth = 25
        self.cellheight = 25
        self.rect = {}

    def draw_grid(self, rows, columns):
        self.myCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.myContainer1)
        self.myCanvas.configure(width=self.cellheight*rows,
                                height=self.cellwidth*columns)
        self.myCanvas.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

        for column in range(rows):
            for row in range(columns):
                x1 = column * self.cellwidth
                y1 = row * self.cellheight
                x2 = x1 + self.cellwidth
                y2 = y1 + self.cellheight
                self.rect[row, column] = self.myCanvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white")

def runApp(rows, columns):
    root = tk.Tk()
    myapp = GridWindow(root)
    myapp.draw_grid(rows, columns)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
runApp(10, 10)
```

With that code the window look like this:

[image]

I managed to fix that with a little hack, but I have no idea why it works. The only diference is that now I'm adding 2 pixels to each canvas dimension and 4 to each cell dimension. The code is the following:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class GridWindow:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent

        self.myContainer1 = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.myContainer1.pack()

        self.cellwidth = 25
        self.cellheight = 25
        self.rect = {}

    def draw_grid(self, rows, columns):
        self.myCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.myContainer1)
        self.myCanvas.configure(width=self.cellheight*rows+2,
                                height=self.cellwidth*columns+2)
        self.myCanvas.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

        for column in range(rows):
            for row in range(columns):
                x1 = column * self.cellwidth+4
                y1 = row * self.cellheight+4
                x2 = x1 + self.cellwidth
                y2 = y1 + self.cellheight
                self.rect[row, column] = self.myCanvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white")

def runApp(rows, columns):
    root = tk.Tk()
    myapp = GridWindow(root)
    myapp.draw_grid(rows, columns)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
runApp(10, 10)
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

So I would appreciate if someone could explain me this behaviour or maybe I'm doing something wrong, any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related to the fact that the coordinate system includes the space required for a border. That is, if the canvas has a border and you draw a line from 0,0 to 0,100, that line will get overdrawn by the border. By default a canvas will have a one or two pixel wide border.

Try setting both the `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` attributes to zero, so that the full width and height of the canvas is drawable. With that, you shouldn't have to add anything to the coordinates.

```
self.myCanvas.configure(borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
```

Comment: Value of -2 is used to remove borders(on tkinter).

Comment: @dsgdfg: what are you talking about? The value isn't additive (or subtractive). Using a value of zero says you want the borderwidth to be zero. Using -2 doesn't do anything more than a value of zero.

Comment: `a = Canvas(root)`, `a.config("highlightthickness") is ('highlightthickness', 'highlightThickness', 'HighlightThickness', '1', '1')`  and  `a.config("bd") is  ('borderwidth', 'borderWidth', 'BorderWidth', '0', '0')` 
Here I have a pixel, 
the second pixel value?

Comment: @dsgdfg: I don't understand your question. What do you mean "I have a pixel, the second pixel value"?

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried adding `borderwidth=0` and `highlightthickness=0` atributes to mycanvas but the only change is that now the oposite lines are not showing. (right and bottom instead left and top)

Comment: @Plorenzo:  When I run your first block of code with the modifications I suggest, the canvas width is 250. The last x and y coordinate that you are drawing is 250. Because the canvas coordinates start at zero, the last visible coordinate will be 249.